# "Single Store Mode" data transfer

Tags: magento2.3, store-view

I have a website where currently only 1 website/store/store view exists. I can therefore switch to "single store mode".

The general problem is, that data was partially edited in the "All Store Views" and partially in the dedicated store view.

My problem occurs, that after switching to the the "single store view":

In the frontend my store view (store_id=7) is visible, but in the backend only the admin store view (store_id =0) is editable. Is there any way to tell magento to use the proper store view? Or do I have to merge all my data from the store view 7 to the store view 0?

Answer (score 0):

For Scope fix use this extension.
https://github.com/cadencelabs/magento2-scope-fix

and for store id 7 data set in default store id that is 0 use the following  sql command:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar p2 INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar p1 ON
    (p1.attribute_id=p2.attribute_id AND p1.entity_id=p2.entity_id AND p1.store_id=7)
SET p2.value = p1.value;



UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text p2 INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text p1 ON
    (p1.attribute_id=p2.attribute_id AND p1.entity_id=p2.entity_id AND p1.store_id=7)
SET p2.value = p1.value;

DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE store_id <> 0;
```

please take backup of your database before perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to share.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22344 - **Data related Magento Issue**

On the front-end, it will always show the Store front-end value as expected. The issue is the setting which is provided at the back-end and how scope works.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25933  - **Field Level System Configuration related Magento Issue**

The general issue like that if website using single store view mode on then all the fields which are on `showInStore=1` scope will be creating issues.

Couple of things you can do.

1. Disable single store view mode
2. Or copy `store_id=7` values to the `store_id=0` but make sure some field values(`showInStore=1`) will be stored on the websites scope also in `core_config_data` or product, category tables.